# php - file_get_contents() or similar function

Tags: php, file, function, file-get-contents

I'm using file_get_contents() to retrieve a list of counties that I have stored in a .txt file. Each county is on its own line.

Is there a way to add quotations around each entry and then a comma following it within the function? One restriction I have is that it would have to populate within the function, and cannot be two separate commands.

Can this be done?

Or maybe I need to look into another function for this?

Comment: Why can you not use two functions?

Comment: `One restriction I have is that it would have to populate within the function` - why? What is the end result you want here - are you writing to a CSV or something?

Comment: What do you mean two separate commands?

Comment: @Jleagle @DaveRandom; I'm editing an application of ours, and we're only allowed to edit a specific file to add an additional field to a form. This file is grabbed by another file which translates the lines and does something with it to populate the fields (which we do not have authorization to access that file). Because of this, adding any other additional commands breaks the operation.

Comment: Any reason why this received a downvote?

Comment: Maybe because of the strange requirements of limiting it to one function. (I didn't downvote).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$countries = file('countries.txt'); // get country list into an array

$fixed_countries = array_map(function($v) { return '"' . trim($v) . '",'; }, $countries);
```

Comment: I went ahead and used a batch script to repopulate my list with the appropriate quotations and commas, reinported the file to the server, then used file() to populate the array. Worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it pretty easily, and it's even better if you use [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) instead of `file_get_contents`:

```
$callback = create_function('$c', 'return "\"".trim($c)."\"";');
$countries = array_map($callback, file('countries.txt'));
return implode(', ', $countries);
```

I have written `$callback` with a syntax that is valid for PHP < 5.3; it's also possible to write it as an anonymous function:

```
$callback = function($c) { return '"'.trim($c).'"'; };
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/TLLx9)**.

Comment: Downvoter: please help me to improve this answer by leaving a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you read something line-by-line, [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) is more appropriate than `file_get_contents`:

```
echo implode(',',
             array_map(function($county) {return '"' . trim($county) . '"';}),
                       file('counties.txt'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure.

```
$countries = explode("\n",'"'.str_replace("\n","\",\n\"",file("countries.txt")));
```

That should convert the file like this:

```
country1
country2
...
```

into an array like this:

```
array('"country1",','"country2",',...).
```

That's what you want, right?

Comment: The result of this would be `array(0 => '"Array')` because you are appending an array to a string.